# google appengine, pycharm, python virtualenv cannot access lib

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, pycharm

I got this error trying to run this code in pycharm:

> ValueError: virtualenv: cannot access lib: No such virtualenv or site directory

this is my code:

```
import os
from google.appengine.ext import vendor
vendor.add('lib')
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine/'):
    GAE_DEV = False
else:
    GAE_DEV = True
```

could someone give me a solution to this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and the info on [this page from the GAE docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) helped me. Particularly, this line:

```
vendor.add(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'lib'))
```

I replaced `vendor.add('lib')` with that line so that the fact that 'lib' is a relative path doesn't cause problems.

Comment: Only option that worked for me after a long SO search. Good tip!

Comment: Remember to add an "import os" at the top of the appengine_config.py.